# What would be the most appropiate programming language for a beginner that wants to build simple web games that involves text input and audio output?

Tags: web, web-applications, textbox, game-engine, html5-audio

First off, apologies if my question is not more precise or clear, but I simply don't have the technical expertise to phrase it correctly. Let me try by giving you an example of the kind of app/game/website? I want to build:

1. the player starts the game by choosing a level
2. they hear a phrase, and they have to type it into the box
3. if the sentence they have typed in is incorrect (doesn't match the sentence heard), errors will be hightlighted, and they are prompted to try again in a new box.
4. when their input is correct, they hear a new sentence 
   and so on

Answer (score 1):

If it's only web you can go with Javascript (to manipulate the front) and some php (if you need to get the audio and sentences from a database for example)

Comment: Thank you for you response. Is there a way to use just one language that can deal with the web thing and the database?

Comment: yes you could use php for both dom manipulation and database manipulation but it's kind of trickier. Javascript is easier for that actually